Is there way to determine a type of OLE object dragged to my window (Outlook message or others)?
I have implemented a drag-and-drop receiver (C++, WINAPI) - see code below.
In the line "999:" It processes CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR or CFSTR_FILECONTENTS formats.
While testing my program I have drag-and-dropped an MS Outlook message only.
It's works fine - I learned to save the message from a storage to disk.
The question is: is there a way is there a way my program can determine - which object was dragged - after all, it could be not only MS Outlook message, but a simple text from Ms Word or other editor, some range from MS Excel etc.
As far as I know, CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR or CFSTR_FILECONTENTS may be used in many cases.
How can I determine - it is the MS Outlook message that is being dragged ?
My code:
HRESULT __stdcall MyDropTarget_CLASS::Drop(IDataObject* pDataObj, DWORD grfKeyState,
    POINTL pt,
    DWORD* pdwEffect) {


    bool ok_get_enum = false, ok_reset = false;

    DragWindowPtr->SetNormalBrush();

    IEnumFORMATETC* ppenumFormatEtc;
    HRESULT res = pDataObj->EnumFormatEtc(DATADIR_GET, &ppenumFormatEtc);
    ok_get_enum = (res == S_OK);
    if (!ok_get_enum)
        std::cout << "EnumFormatEtc ERROR = " << res << std::endl;

    if (ok_get_enum) {
        res = ppenumFormatEtc->Reset();
        ok_reset = (res == S_OK);
        if (!ok_reset)
            std::cout << "EnumFormatEtc.Reset ERROR = " << res << std::endl;
    }

    if (ok_reset) {

        std::cout << "----------------------------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "--------- Enumerating ------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------------------" << std::endl;

        const ULONG ElementsInPortions = 5;
        FORMATETC ItemsArray[ElementsInPortions];
        ULONG FetchedNumber = 0;
        bool DoNext = true;

        const int NameBufferSize = 200;
        wchar_t* NameBufferPtr = (wchar_t*)malloc(NameBufferSize);
        assert(NameBufferPtr != nullptr);
        // -------------------------------

        while (DoNext) {
            DoNext = (res = ppenumFormatEtc->Next(ElementsInPortions, &(ItemsArray[0]), &FetchedNumber)) == S_OK;
            std::cout << "Requested = " << ElementsInPortions << "    Fetched = " << FetchedNumber << std::endl;
            for (ULONG i = 0; i < FetchedNumber; i++) {

                CLIPFORMAT CurFormatCode = ItemsArray[i].cfFormat;
                DWORD CurAspect = ItemsArray[i].dwAspect;
                DWORD CurTymed = ItemsArray[i].tymed;
                LONG LIndex = ItemsArray[i].lindex;

                int ActualNameLength = GetClipboardFormatName(CurFormatCode, NameBufferPtr, NameBufferSize);

                std::cout << "      Format = " << CurFormatCode << "(" << GetFormatName(CurFormatCode) << ")" <<
                    "   Tymed = " << CurTymed << "(" << GetTymedName(CurTymed) << ")";

                if (ActualNameLength > 0)
                    std::wcout << "System Name = " << NameBufferPtr;
                else
                    std::cout << "System Name. LEN = " << ActualNameLength;

                std::cout << std::endl;

                UINT FileDescriptorFormat = FormatsCodesArray[idx_FileDescriptorFormat];
                UINT FileContentsFormat = FormatsCodesArray[idx_FileContentsFormat];

                // Check for format that we got from _RegisterClipboardFormat_
                bool ItsFileDescriptor = (CurFormatCode == FileDescriptorFormat);
                bool ItsFileContents = (CurFormatCode == FileContentsFormat);

                FORMATETC& CurFormatEtc = ItemsArray[i];

                if (ItsFileDescriptor || ItsFileContents ) {

                    999: PROCESS CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR OR CFSTR_FILECONTENTS

                }

            } // for

        } // while

        std::cout << "------ FINISHED ---------" << std::endl;

        if (NameBufferPtr != nullptr) {
            free(NameBufferPtr);
            NameBufferPtr = nullptr;
        }


        ppenumFormatEtc->Release();
    }

    *pdwEffect = DROPEFFECT_COPY;

    return S_OK;
}



Could anyone to answer my question ? Maybe the question is formulated unclearly or need any clarification ?
